# Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /mytheme/functions.php on line 139, woocommerce content-product-archive on line 35

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

This Code From Functions.php line 35

```
    function lyara_woo_change_per_page() {
            $lyara_opt = get_option( 'theme_opt' );
            return $lyara_opt['product_per_page'];
        }
```

This Code From content-product-archive.php line 139

```
    $colwidth = 3;
    if($theme_shopclass=='shop-fullwidth') {
        if(isset($theme_opt)){
            $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $theme_opt['product_per_row_fw'];
            if($woocommerce_loop['columns'] > 0){
                $colwidth = round(12/$woocommerce_loop['columns']);
            }
        }
        $classes[] = ' item-col col-6 col-md-4 col-xl-'.$colwidth ;
    } else {
        if(isset($theme_opt)){
            $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $theme_opt['product_per_row'];
            if($woocommerce_loop['columns'] > 0){
                $colwidth = round(12/$woocommerce_loop['columns']);
            }
        }
        $classes[] = ' item-col col-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-'.$colwidth ;
    }
```

Im getting this error after upgrading php from 7.4 any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

/mytheme/functions.php on line 139:

You use the function "get_option", it return false, in case the option is not found. So $lyara_opt['product_per_page'] is an array offset on bool value.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).